# guestmount is showing fuse: mountpoint is not empty error

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I am trying to mount a .img file to a local directory by the following command in a remote server:

```
guestmount -a ~/image/default.img -i ~/my-mountedpartion
```

And getting the following error

```
fuse: mountpoint is not empty
fuse: if you are sure this is safe, use the 'nonempty' mount option
libguestfs: error: fuse_mount failed: /home/tamzid/my-mountedpartion, see error messages above.
```

But on my local machine, its getting mounted smoothly. How can I solve this?